# Can't embed YouTube video with FancyBox

Tags: jquery, youtube, fancybox

So I'm trying to embed a Youtube Video in a Fancybox pop-up window. However, it does not load, only a blank pop-up window appears.

I have applied the class .fancyYoutube to the link, and have linked my page link to the jquery.

I have a demo site up now for testing purposes which you can find here:
http://stevepolitodesign.comlu.com/

The piece that is not working is located in the "portfolio" section and is at the bottom left.

Here is the HTML for the affected code:

```
<div class="myWork">
 <a href="http://youtu.be/aXC4BORr3jI" class="fancyYoutube">
 <p class="caption">
 <span class="bold">category:</span> <br />
 motion graphics <br /><br />
 <span class="bold">client:</span> <br />
 camp harrington<br />
 </p>
 <img src="images/thumbnails_16.jpg" width="130" height="130" alt="Camp Harrington   Promotional Video"  class="thumbnail"/>
 </a>
</div>
```

Here is the affected jquery:

```
$("a.fancyYoutube").fancybox({
'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
'padding' : 0,
'autoScale' : false,
'transitionOut' : 'fade',
'width' : 680,
'height' : 495,
'type' : 'swf'
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually the `html` in your site is

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXC4BORr3jI&amp;feature=channel_video_title" class="fancyYoutube">
```

if you want to keep using that `html` then try this script:

```
$("a.fancyYoutube").click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
            'padding'       : 0,
            'autoScale'     : false,
            'transitionIn'  : 'none',
            'transitionOut' : 'none',
            'title'         : this.title,
            'width'     : 680,
            'height'        : 495,
            'href'          : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
            'type'          : 'swf',
            'swf'           : {
                 'wmode'        : 'transparent',
                'allowfullscreen'   : 'true'
            }
        });

    return false;
});
```

Note that the script will work for the current html and fancybox v1.3.4 only. If you change the html (or the fancybox version) then you may need to tweak the script

Answer (score 3):

http://youtu.be/aXC4BORr3jI redirects to http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXC4BORr3jI&feature=youtu.be.

This page contains the [**`X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header) response header,
which prevents the page from being loaded in a frame at a different domain.

Use the `/embed/` URL for including the video in a frame: http://www.youtube.com/embed/aXC4BORr3jI
An additional advantage is that only the video is shown, without comments, related videos, etc.

Comment: Thanks Rob, however after making this adjustment I still noticed not change.

Comment: I still don't see `/embed/` in your site.

Comment: I had made the edit locally, sorry. I should have uploaded my site after the update.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `'type' : 'swf'` to `'type' : 'iframe'` and it started working. Along with the "/embed/" tips, of course.

It's logical, since http://www.youtube.com/embed/... URL returns HTML code, and not SWF content itself.